# ExtJs keys form.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

[image]

keys config working on `Ext.window.Window` but it dose not effect on `Ext.form.Panel`.

i have tried many method，but still did not work. How can i resolve this?

```
Ext.define('Settings.view.security.service.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'service',
    requires: [
        'Settings.controller.Service',
    ],
    viewModel: { type: 'service' }, 
    title: l.cp.service.self,
    controller: 'service',
    trackResetOnLoad:true,
    frame: false,
    padding: YsCfg.listPadding,
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelWidth: 180,
        labelAlign: 'left',
        maxLength: 63,
        msgTarget: 'side',
    },
    //fieldDefaults: YsCfg.fieldDefaults,
    border: false,
    scrollable: true,
    items:[{
        ...
    }],
    bbar: {
        itemId: 'bbar',
        defaults: {minWidth: YsCfg.btnMinWidth},
        items: ['->', {
            text: l.cp.common.save,
            ui: 'ys-theme',
            handler: 'handlerSave'
        }, {
            text: l.cp.common.cancel,
            ui: 'ys-theme',
            handler: 'handlerCancel'
        }, '->']
    },
    keys: {
        key: Ext.event.Event.ENTER, 
        fn: function(obj){
            var controller = Ext.getCmp('control-panel').down('service').getController();
            if(controller){
                controller.handlerSave();
            }
        },
        scope: this
    },
    listeners: {
        show: 'showOpt',
        boxready: 'readyOpt',
    },
});
```

Comment: Use code snippets instead of images.

Comment: Can you make fiddle illustrating your issue or atleast add full component definition?

Comment: keys: {
        key: Ext.event.Event.ENTER, 
        fn: function(obj){
            var controller = Ext.getCmp('control-panel').down('service').getController();
            if(controller){
                controller.handlerSave();
            }
        },
        scope: this
    },

Comment: Which ExtJS version? [I did not find `Ext.window.Window.keys` in the 6.2.1 reference.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.window.Window.html)

Comment: Try to reproduce your bug in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)

Comment: Extjs version 6.0.0